# Closing a redis subscription and ending the go routine when websocket connection closes

Tags: go, redis

I'm pushing events from a redis subscription to a client who is connected via websocket. I'm having trouble unsubscribing and exiting the redis go routine when the client disconnects the websocket.

Inspired by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35510557/how-to-kill-blocking-go-routine), here's what I have thus far. I'm able to receive subscription events and send messages to the client via websocket, but when the client closes the websocket and the `defer close(done)` code fires, my `case b, ok := <-done:` doesn't fire. It seems to be overloaded by the default case???

```
package api

import (
    ...

    "github.com/garyburd/redigo/redis"
    "github.com/gorilla/websocket"
)

func wsHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var upgrader = websocket.Upgrader{
        ReadBufferSize:  1024,
        WriteBufferSize: 1024,
    }

    conn, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
    if err != nil {
        HandleError(w, err)
        return
    }
    defer conn.Close()

    done := make(chan bool)
    defer close(done)

    for {
        var req WSRequest
        err := conn.ReadJSON(&req)
        if err != nil {
            HandleWSError(conn, err)
            return
        }
        defer conn.Close()

        go func(done chan bool, req *WSRequest, conn *websocket.Conn) {
            rc := redisPool.Get()
            defer rc.Close()

            psc := redis.PubSubConn{Conn: rc}
            if err := psc.PSubscribe(req.chanName); err != nil {
                HandleWSError(conn, err)
                return
            }
            defer psc.PUnsubscribe()

            for {
                select {
                case b, ok := <-done:
                    if !ok || b == true {
                        return
                    }
                default:
                    switch v := psc.Receive().(type) {
                    case redis.PMessage:
                        err := handler(conn, req, v)
                        if err != nil {
                            HandleWSError(conn, err)
                        }

                    case redis.Subscription:
                         log.Printf("%s: %s %d\n", v.Channel, v.Kind, v.Count)

                    case error:
                         log.Printf("error in redis subscription; err:\n%v\n", v)
                         HandleWSError(conn, v)

                    default:
                        // do nothing...
                        log.Printf("unknown redis subscription event type; %s\n", reflect.TypeOf(v))
                    }
                }
            }
        }(done, &req, conn)
    }
}
```

Comment: Why does application get a new connection and subscribe on every message received?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding how `redis.PubSubConn` is working. Each client wants to subscribe to a unique channel.

Comment: I simplified my actual code, there's a channel name string that each websocket client passes.

Comment: Please give a high-level description of what the application is doing.  Describe the messages sent to and from the websocket client and how the messages relate to pubsub messages and channel names.

Comment: A trigger in my postgres db sends a notification whenever a certain table changes. A listener in go takes that table change event and publishes it over redis. The channel name is structured in such a way that it can later be pattern matched by interested clients. Clients connect to the server via websocket and send a payload describing the types of table change events they are interested in. The channel they subscribe to is generated based on this payload. There are an infinite number of possible channel names for clients to subscribe to based on the payload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make these changes to break out of the read loop when done serving the websocket connection:

- Maintain a slice of the Redis connections created for this websocket connection.
- Unsubscribe all connections when done.
- Modify the read loop to return when the subscription count is zero.

Here's the code:

```
func wsHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var upgrader = websocket.Upgrader{
        ReadBufferSize:  1024,
        WriteBufferSize: 1024,
    }

    conn, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
    if err != nil {
        HandleError(w, err)
        return
    }
    defer conn.Close()

    // Keep slice of all connections. Unsubscribe all connections on exit.
    var pscs []redis.PubSubConn
    defer func() {
        for _, psc := range rcs {
           psc.Unsubscribe() // unsubscribe with no args unsubs all channels
        }
    }()

    for {
        var req WSRequest
        err := conn.ReadJSON(&req)
        if err != nil {
            HandleWSError(conn, err)
            return
        }

        rc := redisPool.Get()
        psc := redis.PubSubConn{Conn: rc}
        pscs = append(pscs, psc)

        if err := psc.PSubscribe(req.chanName); err != nil {
            HandleWSError(conn, err)
            return
        }

        go func(req *WSRequest, conn *websocket.Conn) {
            defer rc.Close()
            for {
                switch v := psc.Receive().(type) {
                case redis.PMessage:
                    err := handler(conn, req, v)
                    if err != nil {
                        HandleWSError(conn, err)
                    }

                case redis.Subscription:
                     log.Printf("%s: %s %d\n", v.Channel, v.Kind, v.Count)
                     if v.Count == 0 {
                         return
                     }

                case error:
                     log.Printf("error in redis subscription; err:\n%v\n", v)
                     HandleWSError(conn, v)

                default:
                    // do nothing...
                    log.Printf("unknown redis subscription event type; %s\n", reflect.TypeOf(v))
                }
            }
        }(&req, conn)
    }
}
```

The code in the question and this answer dial multiple Redis connections for each websocket client. A more typical and scalable approach is to share a single Redis pubsub connection across multiple clients. The typical approach may be appropriate for your application given the high-level description, but I am still unsure of what you are trying to do given the code in the question.

Comment: Thanks for this! Just reading the code, it definitely seems like it will accomplish unsubscribing. I'll give it a try.

"A more typical and scalable approach is to share a single Redis pubsub connection across multiple clients." Would it be possible to share a single pubsub connection across multiple websocket connections, but then have each websocket subscribe to a unique channel and only receive messages from that channel? I don't want a websocket receiving messages from channels it is not interested in.

Comment: You will need to write a few lines of code to demultiplex the pubsub messages to share a single redis connection.  A tiny step in the right direction is to use a single Redis connection per client.  This is probably an easy change, but I don't know for sure because I don't understand what you are trying to do (there's a big gap between the high level description and the code).  If a client can only subscribe to a single redis channel, then the change is simple.

Comment: "You will need to write a few lines of code to demultiplex the pubsub messages to share a single redis connection." Imagine if I have 10k websocket connections and 1k table change events per second. I'll then need to be doing 10MM message demultiplexes per second. I could demultiplex messages per websocket client without redis and simply use postgres notify / listen. I chose to add redis to shift the burden of that demultiplexing off my server and onto redis.

Comment: You need to demux 1k events per second, not 10mm. Sending the data to Redis and back will not offload work from the frontend server because the cost of demuxing an event (it's basically a map lookup) is tiny compared to the cost of sending or receiving a Redis message.